# ruby の、モジュールを含んだフルのクラス名文字列から、クラスオブジェクトを取得したい

Tags: ruby

たとえば、以下の文字列があったとします。

```
"FooModule::BarClass"
```

このような、モジュールをフルに含むクラス名の文字列から、 `FooModule::BarClass` のクラスオブジェクトを取得したいと考えました。

eval すれば一発のような気もしますが、脆弱性やバグの温床になりそうなので、できれば避けたいと思っています。

#### 質問

- ruby の、モジュールを含んだフルのクラス名の文字列から、それが表すクラスオブジェクトを取得したいです。これを実現する、そのまま eval 以外の方法などありますでしょうか。

Comment: `Kernel.const_get("FooModule::BarClass")` でよい様な。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubyであれば`Kernel.const_get`で十分ですが、
Railsであれば、constantizeを使うのがよいです。
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize

Answer (score 1):

@metropolis さんの指摘通り、 `Module#const_get` は、そのままでも、今回質問で述べた挙動をする様子です。

> This method will recursively look up constant names if a namespaced
>   class name is provided.  For example:
>
> ```
> module Foo; class Bar; end end
> Object.const_get 'Foo::Bar'
> ```
>
> – `ri Module#const_get`